# Combination and Permutation with merging function

Tags: delphi, merge, combinations, permutation, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a n number of strings which I need to merge into n number of strings in multiple combinations/permutations. the string cannot repeat itself and combination in single merge doesnt matter ( S1, S2 ) = ( S2, S1 )...

This is used when building a tree model and it decided which combination of characteristics is the best to merge...

This code is what I've wrote for permutations. List contains characteristic attributes, Splits is the number of splits I want to make , SplitList return which attributes need to be merge together... for binary tree I input "2" for Splits and for non-binary tree I run a cycle to return the best value for each of the splits .

I.E.
I have "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F".
If i Need to merge into 2 string 
2. "A,B,C" and "D,E,F" or "A,C,E" and "B,D,F" or "A,E,F" and "B,C,D"
3. "A,B, and "C,D" and "E,F" or "A,D" and "C,B" and "E,F"
Also minimum number in a string is 1, maximum n-1.
I.E
2. "A" and "B,C,D,E,F" or "C" and "A,B,D,E,F" is a valid merging

```
function TSplitEngine.doTest(List: TList; Splits: Integer; var SplitList : TArray<Integer>): Double;
var
   i, j, SplitNo, Pointer : Integer;
   tmpNode : TDTreeNode;
   CurRes, CurOut : Double;
   TestArr : RTestArr;
   ResArr: TArray<double>;
   SplitStr : String;
   DoSplit, FindSplit : Boolean;
   TestList : TArray<Integer>;
begin
   Result := DefaultVal;
   SetLength( TestList, Splits );
   for i := 0 to Length( TestList ) - 1 do
       TestList[ i ] := i + 1;
   TestArr.Size := Splits + 1;
   DoSplit := True;
   while DoSplit do
   begin
      Inc(Iteration);
      TestArr.Clear;
      for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
      begin
          tmpNode := TDTreeNode( List[ i ] );
          j := 0;
          FindSplit := True;
          While ( j < Length( TestList ) ) and ( FindSplit )  do
          begin
             if i < TestList[ j ] then
             begin
                Combine Characteristics
                FindSplit := False;
             end
             else if ( i >= TestList[ Length( TestList ) - 1 ] ) then
             begin
                Combine  last split characteristics
                FindSplit := False;
             end;
             inc( j );
          end;
          TestArr.AllTotal := TestArr.AllTotal + ( tmpNode.Goods + tmpNode.Bads );
      end;
      //CalcNode returns the result of this particular splits
      CurRes := CalcNode( TestArr );
      SetLength( ResArr, 2 );
      ResArr[ 1 ] := CurRes;

      if IsBetter( CurRes, Result ) then
      begin
         Result := CurRes;
         SplitList := Copy( TestList, 0, Length( TestList ) );
      end;
      SplitNo := 1;
      FindSplit := True;
      //Move the split like a pointer...
      i  := Length( TestList ) - 1;
      while ( i >= 0 ) and FindSplit do
      begin
         if ( TestList[ i ] < ( List.Count - SplitNo ) ) then
         begin
            Pointer := TestList[ i ] + 1;
            for j := i to Length( TestList ) - 1 do
            begin
               TestList[ j ] := Pointer;
               inc( Pointer );
            end;

            FindSplit := False;
         end
         else if ( i = 0 ) then
            DoSplit := False;
         inc ( SplitNo );
         Dec( i );
      end;
   end;
end;
```

the permutation code seems to be working and the only thing to do would be to tidy it up.

I've tried a few times to convert this code to do combinations but never seemed to work.

Comment: Is it not just a case of starting j at I+1 instead of zero? I haven't checked all the code out - it seems awfully complicated. I prefer to do combinations and permutations by recursion anyway. It is a lot less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have old code for generation of set partitions with set size <= 10 (due to set comparison implemented through strings). Note that number of partitions for n=10 is 115975 (Bell number).

Procedure generates non-repeating partitions of set into KP parts, so you have to go through all KP values.

Part of output including some two-parts and some three-parts partitions:

```
1,4 | 2,3,5 | 
1,4,5 | 2,3 | 
1,5 | 2,3,4 | 
1 | 2 | 3,4,5 | 
1 | 2,3 | 4,5 | 
1 | 2,3,4 | 5 | 

  procedure generate_multi_partitions(values: array of Integer; KP: Integer);
  var
    n, i: Integer;
    avail: array of Boolean;
    output: array of TStringList;

  procedure foo(k: Integer); forward;

    procedure bar(k, i: Integer);
    var
      j: Integer;
    begin
      output[k].add(IntToStr(values[i]));
      avail[i] := False;
      foo(k + 1);
      for j := i + 1 to n - 1 do
        if avail[j] and ((j = 0) or (values[j - 1] <> values[j]) or
          (not avail[j - 1])) then
          bar(k, j);
      output[k].Delete(output[k].Count - 1);
      avail[i] := True;
    end;

    procedure foo(k: Integer);
    var
      i, j: Integer;
      s: string;
    begin
      if (k >= 2) and (output[k - 2].CommaText > output[k - 1].CommaText) then
        Exit;
      if k = KP - 1 then begin
        output[k].Clear;
        for i := 0 to n - 1 do
          if avail[i] then
            output[k].add(IntToStr(values[i]));
        if (output[k].Count > 0) and
          ((k = 0) or (output[k - 1].CommaText <= output[k].CommaText)) then
        begin
          s := '';
          for j := 0 to KP - 1 do
            s := s + output[j].CommaText + ' | ';
          Memo1.Lines.add(s);
        end;
        output[k].Clear;
      end
      else
        for i := 0 to n - 1 do
          if avail[i] then begin
            bar(k, i);
            Exit;
          end;
    end;

  begin
    n := length(values);
    SetLength(avail, n);
    SetLength(output, KP);
    for i := 0 to KP - 1 do
      output[i] := TStringList.Create;
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
      avail[i] := True;
    foo(0);
    for i := 0 to KP - 1 do
      output[i].Free;
  end;

var
  parts: Integer;
begin
  for parts := 1 to 5 do
    generate_multi_partitions([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], parts);
end;
```